# Get a value from an attribute and add it as another attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, href, attr

How can I use jQuery to get a string of text from the `onclick` attribute and set it as the `href` attribute.

Here's the fiddle I'm working with: http://jsfiddle.net/MBmt5/

I want to take only `TrackPackage.asp?track=95213&amp;ship=OTHER&amp;ShippingMethod=3` from the `onclick` attribute and prop it to an `href` attribute

So that it would end up looking like this: http://jsfiddle.net/52Nha/

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to accomplish this. Can anybody help me? Must be compatible with jQuery 1.4.2. Thanks.

**Update**

Of course I'd begin with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('span.trackpackagebutton').closest('a').removeAttr('href');
});
```

​

Comment: is it possible to have the onclick handler to be a seperate function? Where do you get the TrackPackage.asp?... link from? is it a dynamic one?

Comment: It's definitely a dynamic one, and I cannot modify the anchors markup...

Comment: Dude, seriously... you're still struggling with this? Is this a legacy app , or are there active backend devs working on it? If some one is still maintaining the backend for the love all that is holy have them change the link generation! They shouldnt be writing directly in the onclick any way.

Comment: @prodigitalson I wish...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugly but I hope this will help you.

```
$('a').attr('href', 
            $('a')[0].getAttribute('onclick')
            .replace("window.open('", '').split(',')[0].replace("'", ''))
      .removeAttr('onclick');​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/MBmt5/5/

Note: Based on your markup structure you can use the right selector and reuse the above code.

E.g: The below code will execute this logic for all the anchors on the page which have `onclick` attribute which has `window.open`.

```
$('a[onclick^="window.open"]').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('href', 
                this.getAttribute('onclick')
                .replace("window.open('", '').split(',')[0].replace("'", ''))
           .removeAttr('onclick');​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
});
```

Comment: This assumes that there is only one <a> anchor tag in the page?

Comment: This is just a sample code based on OP's fiddle. Based on the markup the code can be reused as desired.

Comment: @lowerkey - It does work, I tested in Chrome. Which browser are you using?

Comment: @lowerkey - Can you respond so that I will improve my answer?

Comment: @ ShankarSangoli   - issue seems to be 1.4.2 won't retrieve the attribute

Comment: Ok, fixed it using `getAttribute()` native JavaScript api. Updated my answer and the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MBmt5/5/

Comment: @ShankarSangoli: I tried Chrome and Firefox. You say it works, so I guess I'm alone with the problem... I'll remove the downvote. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

- http://jsfiddle.net/MBmt5/2/

Comment: Here's a version that works in 1.4.4, should work with 1.4.2: http://jsfiddle.net/MBmt5/4/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/GaZGv/1

```
var $a = $('span.trackpackagebutton').closest('a');
var href = $a.attr('onclick').split('(')[1].split(',')[0].replace(/'/g, '');
$a.attr('href', href).removeAttr('onclick');

alert(href)​
```

Comment: should be compatible with 1.4.2...not using anything new in it

Comment: wow..testing in fiddle and it has troubles in 1.4...am surprised,  trying a few things